# how to extract strings in between period, asterisk and words

Tags: powershell

I have this powershell script. The idea is to generate a report but the I need to split the string on "certificate.common_name" and put on separate column.

here's my script, and this works okay, however, I cannot assume the client code will always start in position 7.

```
$WriteStr = $order.certificate.common_name, $order.date_created, $order.certificate.days_remaining, $order.certificate.common_name.Substring(7,2), $Tag -join, ","
```

so basically, I want to get  "1z" on this string(certificate.common_name)  "*.test.1z.sample.com"

Comment: $order.certificate.common_name.Split('.')[2]